# Why does this UIScrollView not behave properly?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I have a project where I need a custom tabbar, a navigationcontroller and a pageviewcontroller in one view. I have succeeded in creating this, but I am encountering a bug that I cannot solve:

The first viewcontroller in my pageviewcontroller does not set its view height properly (or rather its Y value). The moment scrolling occurs this gets set to the correct height.

I have created a minimal testproject [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kg5ax8ugi27vmci/TestScrollShizzle.zip?dl=0).

**Edit:** I have tried setting `collectionView.contentInset` and `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` with all possible combinations, but to no avail. Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were confused with navigation bar and bottom bar. Here is how it should work in you project in storyboard for PageViewController:
 [image]
Also, I removed line `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false`, and unchecked it in storyboard.
 You can get fixed project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/omjl8q7am4kejyw/AABtA0aX6h3zntOZo7r0rc8Aa?dl=0)

Comment: Thanks man! I'm sorry I wasn't on time to award the bounty. I am very pleased with this answer! I will read up on this "extend edges" thing and I will probably learn quite a bit about how `UIScrollView`s work. Thanks again!

Comment: So I had this and another issue was that my `UINavigationBar` did not yet have the correct height, so I checked if it's `nil` and used a hardcoded value to prevent the issue from arising

Answer (score 3):

Try to add `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false` for your pageviewcontroller. Notice the first page is not under top bar, while it is after scrolling.

Comment: This works. A page view controller also uses a scroll view so the view controller’s automatic insets are applied to it. The page view controller’s scroll view is also preventing scrolling to the top when tapping the status bar.